# How to convert local time to Argentina time?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to draw 4 analog clocks. first is basis on Iran time, second : Argentina time, third: Brazil time , fourth: France time.
I get the system's time (basis Iran's time) and show it on my analog clock. But I don't know how to get 3 others time and show them.

```
 GLfloat h,m,s;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: I think more people will be able to help if you also post the code you are using to get the current time!

Comment: Except that you're using a `GLfloat` variable (which is just like any other float), I see no reason to put OpenGL in the question here - OpenGL is not relevant to your problem at all.

Comment: Just an idea to let you or someone else find the answer: convert local time to UTC time by removing time-offset and then reapply offset for each different timezone

Comment: The majority of the code you've posted is irrelevant to your question about timezones, and you should edit to remove it. The clock drawing code is simply unnecessary wasted space.

Comment: @J.Rahmati: you're right. but my  problem isn't it. I want the command that give this

Comment: by _gives this_ you mean to get the timeoffset?

Comment: @J.Rahmati: which command converts local time to UTC and which command reapplies the time offset?

Comment: Sorry I have to search that part. I only know the concept right now and commented it in case someone else could apply the concept faster that I would do!

Comment: Please add tags for the programming language you're using... Visual C++? Are you using the Managed Extensions? In that case you use the `DateTimeOffset` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the language, but I am guessing you are using c++. If that is the case then you can use gmtime function like explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/) to get UTC time and then add then adjust the hour by adding the UTc offset for argentinia (timeinfo->tm_hour = -3 or whatever the correct syntax is)